# Search for a filename substring, and move matches to a location based on the search pattern

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, string-matching

I am trying to match a sub-string within file names using a command in Windows, and move resulting files to another directory named using that search string.

Given example files, `ABC123.txt`, and `DEF123.txt`, if the input string value matches - `ABC` then it needs to be moved to a directory path `input\abc`, and if the input string matches `DEF`, then it needs to be moved to a different directory `input\def`.

I tried using:

```
FINDSTR -i -r -c:"ABC" ABC123.txt
```

But it is trying to match the string with the file content, and my requirement is just to search the filename.

I tried using `findstr` along with an `if` condition, but I think I am using the wrong syntax.

Comment: `Findstr` is not the command for the task; `Dir` is. Use a `for /f` loop to capture the output of the `dir` command and the search term.
 `For /f "delims=" %%G in ('dir /b *ABC*.txt')Do Echo(Move "%%~G" "Path\to\input\ABC"`

Comment: or simply `move "ABC*" "destination\"` or `move "*ABC*" "destination\"`